# What is the best way to select rows with column containing a list of keys?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a pictures table and in each row I have a column with keys to displaying elements. Each picture may have multiple displaying elements. What is the most efficient way to store them so the selection by a displaying element won't take long?

How helpful can Geometry types be in this case?
Could the option of storing the keys as a multi-point sequence be a solution for fast query?

Comment: You need [many-to-many relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) for your tables.

Comment: This sounds like Databases 101. Try to learn the basics before worrying about performance.

Comment: @Stijn where should I start?

Comment: There's a [Wikibook on relational database design](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design) but from a brief look it's probably more complicated than needed. Searching for *relational database 101* should net you lots of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *many-to-many relation* and should be  mapped with an additional table

```
table pictures
columns id, name, ...

table elements
columns id, name, ...

table picture_elements
columns picture_id, element_id
```

Comment: In case of 300k+ of pictures with, suppose, 5 displaying elements we've got possible 1.5M rows. Efficient?

Comment: Yes, it is efficient with proper indexing. And it is also how it should be done.